# Selectively deleting images uploaded to Azure blob (Django/Python project)

Tags: django, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

In a Django (Python) project, I'm using Azure blobs to store photos uploaded by users. The code simply goes something like this:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobService

blob_service = BlobService(account_name=accountName, account_key=accountKey)
blob_service.put_blob(
            'pictures',
            name, # including folder
            content_str, # image as stream
            x_ms_blob_type='BlockBlob',
            x_ms_blob_content_type=content_type,
            x_ms_blob_cache_control ='public, max-age=3600, s-maxage=86400'
        )
```

My question is: what's the equivalent method to `delete` an uploaded photo in my particular scenario? I'm writing a task to periodically clean up my data models, and so want to get rid of images associated to them as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
blob_service.delete_blob(container_name, blob_name)
```

You can also delete an entire container:

```
blob_service.delete_container(container_name)
```

There are a few extra parameters which will be helpful to you if you're trying to delete snapshots, deal with leases, etc.

Note that `put_blob()` is defined in [blockblobservice.py](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/azure/storage/blob/blockblobservice.py), while `delete_blob()` is defined in [baseblobservice.py](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/azure/storage/blob/baseblobservice.py) (deletes are going to be the same, whether page, block, or append blob).

Comment: Thanks for the assist David. I checked out the `delete_blob` and `delete_container` methods. There's no way to delete selective blob objects in **bulk** is there? I have to delete multiple objects (but not everything in the container); currently I'm looping through a for loop to do it.