# Matillion: Delete files from Azure Blob Storage Container and Windows Fileshare

Tags: azure, fileshare, matillion

I have a use case where I am Transferring XML files from Windows fileshare to Azure Blob Storage and then loading data to Snowflake Tables. I am using Matillion to achieve this.

The Windows Fileshare gets Zipped XML file which contains .xml and .xml.chk files. I am using Azure Blob Storage component of Matillion to Copy the .xml files to Snowflake table and have set Purge = True to delete them afterwards.

I need help in deleting the leftover .xml.chk files from Blob Storage Container. Also, once the data loading is complete, I would like to delete the zipped files from Windows Fileshare.

Thanks,
Shivroopa

Answer (score 1):

you can delete the files from blob storage using the matillion python script component (orchestration->scripting->Python script)

here is an example of python code to delete blob items and containers
[Delete Blob Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58900507/upload-and-delete-azure-storage-blob-using-azure-storage-blob-or-azure-storage)

I don't see a way to delete files on the windows machine from Matillion other than creating an API endpoint on the fileshare and calling the API from Matillion.